# WordPress Child-Themes Altering php Files

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a Child Theme in WordPress and I've been editing a lot of the PHP files and instead of editing the main file, I've been copying it over to my child theme just to change a few words. For example, I had just copied over the entire `index.php` file in the parent theme, to my child theme just to replace the text on the "Read More" button.

Is it required that I copy over the entire file or can I somehow just edit that little snippet? I have done the same thing for my `footer.php` and `header.php` and as far as I know, you can only do what I'm after in the `function.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Generally, if you want to change a file you have to copy it.

On the other hand, for a lot of cases hooks exist that you can use. For the example you mentioned:

```
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'modify_read_more_link' , 100 );
function modify_read_more_link() {
  return '<a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">Your Read More Link Text</a>';
}
```

(Example from http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More)

You place this in the functions.php of your child theme.

The available filters are described [in the filter reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference).

Comment: I don't think this works anymore... `the_content_more_link` filter isn't even in the filter reference page you linked. It might just be the theme I'm using.

Comment: The filter Reference is not 100% complete (it says so at the top). The filter is documented in the [Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content_more_link/). You could try increasing the priority with the third parameter of [add_filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter). I added this to the answer.